# Connect to PCF Cloud Config Server Service remotely

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have created a PCF Config Server Service in PCF. when i deploy my springboot app that acts as a Config service client, deploy to PCF and bind it to the Config server service, it seamlessly pulls the configs and all is good.

My issue is, I am unable to connect to the PCF Config Server from my springboot app while running the app locally from my laptop.

Based on various documentation I created the Service Key for my Config Server service and modified my bootstrap.yml as below.

I am getting 401 Unauthorized error. 
INFO 22180 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: https://config-8660fe8f-2b6b-4171-bd7f-36f3a60ec48a.apps.pcfepg2wi.gm.com
WARN 22180 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 401 Unauthorized
INFO 22180 --- [           main] com.gm.mms.extfile.Application           : tartupProfileInfo - The following profiles are active: dev

```
spring:
  application:
    name: external-file-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://config-8660fe8f-2b6b-4171-bd7f- 
36f3a60ec48a.apps.pcfepg2wi.gm.com
      username: <username-here>
      password: <password-here>
      client_secret: RwKMmAhOzuz8
      client_id: p-config-server-ebcd8a29-2615-4924-88bb-b4188d50d2b5
      access_token_uri: https://p-spring-cloud- 
 services.uaa.sys.pcfepg2wi.gm.com/oauth/token
      label: develop

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your connecting to the PCF Config server ? Why can't you spin-up a config server locally and tie your app to your local config server ?

Comment: the purpose of connecting to PCF config server is to pull the application.yml config from git. when i already have Config server as a PCF service why should i spin(code) a config server locally ?

Comment: Spinning up a config server locally is pretty easy (download a spring boot app, keep `@EnableConfigServer` annotation in main method, point your git-repo in `bootstrap.yml` .. Now you are all-set .. This way you can easily test your application locally and would be conducive for your `Junit` test cases also ... I have really not seen any app-teams / anchors pulling their configuration from a server sitting in data center to test it locally .. You can do, but i really don't find any benefits

Comment: This is very common issue you'll see when try to connect PCF marketplace service from local and most of the time it's because of firewall rules.
Check with your PCF team if they have disabled the connectivity from outside of PCF foundation.

Comment: @Arun - thanks for the insight. i'd pursue that solution. you might be right..i have done extensive search and couldnt find anyone trying it my way.

Comment: @Avhi - the PCF team asked me to create service keys to access the service. i had all service key credentials in hte bootstrap, but to no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: Not sure you can connect any PCF marketplace service from local
>   if Firewall rules are setup to disable the external connectivity.

If there is no connectivity issue then you should you be able to connect it using following workaround(worked for me)

Add following environment variables in your Spring Boot App Configuration

1. **TRUST_CERT** -  your PCF foudantion URL
2. **VCAP_APPLICATION** -  VCAP_APPLICATION JSON compact formatted*(You can get this `json` in your `PCF` app `Environment Variables` under `application_env_json`)
3. **VCAP_SERVICES** -  VCAP_SERVICES JSON compact formatted*(You can get this `json` in your `PCF` app `Environment Variables` under `system_env_json`)

You can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) website to format `JSON` data [Select `Compact` JSON Template]

[image]

Comment: how does your bootstrap.yml look like ?

Comment: Only application name is required in `bootstrap.yml`
In your case:
`spring:
  application: external-file-service`

Comment: @Khan379 great.. (y)

Comment: @Avhi Will it also take care of generation token and authentication?